# create nested json array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

I am newbie to php ,trying to create a nested json array in php but not getting the desired json format.

desired format

```
{
  "offers": [
    {
      "offerId": "1",
      "offerName": "shirts",
      "price": "1980",
      "storeName": "peter england"
    },
    {
      "offerId": "2",
      "offerName": "shirts",
      "storeId": "3",
      "price": "2970",
      "storeName": "peter england"
    }
  ],
  "brands": [
    {
      "brandName": "peter england",
      "brandId": "5"
    },
    {
      "brandName": "ruggers",
      "brandId": "4"
    }
  ],
  "stores": [
    {
      "storeName": "peter england",
      "storeId": "3"
    },
    {
      "storeName": "peter england",
      "storeId": "4"
    }
  ],
  "filters": [
    {
      "0": {
        "filter": "M",
        "filterId": "11"
      },
      "1": {
        "filter": "S",
        "filterId": "12"
      },
      "filterName": "size"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "filter": "red",
        "filterId": "13"
      },
      "1": {
        "filter": "blue",
        "filterId": "14"
      },
      "filterName": "colour"
    }
  ]
}
```

but getting this format

```
{
  "offers": [
    {
      "offerId": "1",
      "offerName": "shirts",
      "image": "http://www.offersmashup.com/testing/store/upload/sml_p1.jpg",
      "brandId": "5",
      "storeId": "3",
      "price": "1980",
      "offer": "Off-20",
      "storeName": "peter england"
    },
    {
      "offerId": "2",
      "offerName": "shirts",
      "image": "http://www.offersmashup.com/testing/store/upload/sml_p2.jpg",
      "brandId": "5",
      "storeId": "3",
      "price": "2970",
      "offer": "Off-30",
      "storeName": "peter england"
    }
  ],
  "brands": [
    {
      "brandName": "peter england",
      "brandId": "5"
    },
    {
      "brandName": "ruggers",
      "brandId": "4"
    }
  ],
  "stores": [
    {
      "storeName": "peter england",
      "storeId": "3"
    },
    {
      "storeName": "peter england",
      "storeId": "4"
    }
  ],
  "filters": {
    "0": {
      "filter": "M",
      "filterId": "11"
    },
    "1": {
      "filter": "S",
      "filterId": "12"
    },
    "filterName": "size"
  }
}
```

my php code is below

```
$dbFactory = new DBFactory();

$jsonArray = array();

if ($subcatid != '')
    {

    $p2 = $dbFactory->sel_product3($subcatid, $area_value);
    if (count($p2) > 0)
        {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($p2); $j++)
            {
            $p3 = $dbFactory->sel_store($p2[$j]['STORE_ID']);
            $temp['offers'][] = array(
                "offerId" => $p2[$j]['P_ID'],
                "offerName" => $p2[$j]['P_NAME'],
                "image" => $url . $p2[$j]['P_ID'] . '.jpg',
                "brandId" => $p2[$j]['BRAND_ID'],
                "storeId" => $p2[$j]['STORE_ID'],
                "price" => $p2[$j]['PRICE'],
                "offer" => $p2[$j]['OFFER'],
                "storeName" => $p3[0]['S_NAME']
            );
            $jsonArray = $temp;
            }
        }

    }
// filters code=================
/*code to retrive brnads and stores goes here*/

foreach($res as $value)
    {
    $br = $dbFactory->sel_brand($value);
    $temp["brands"][] = array("brandName" => $br[0]['BRAND_NAME'] ,"brandId"=>$br[0]['BID'] );
   $jsonArray = $temp;
    }

foreach($store_value as $value)
    {
    $sr = $dbFactory->sel_store($value);
    $temp["stores"][] = array("storeName" => $sr[0][S_NAME] ,"storeId"=>$sr[0][S_ID] );
   $jsonArray = $temp;
    }

$parentCatId = $dbFactory->getparentcatId($subcatid);
$fg = $dbFactory->get_filtergroup($parentCatId[0]['PARENT_ID']);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fg); $i++)
    {
    $f = $dbFactory->sel_filter($fg[$i][F_ID]);
    $temp['filters'] =  array();
    $temp['filters']['filterName'] = $fg[$i][FNAME];

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($f); $j++)
        {
        $temp['filters'][] = array("filter"=>$f[$j][FNAME],"filterId"=>$f[$j][F_ID] );
        }

    array_push($jsonArray, $temp);
    }

$jsonArray = $temp;
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

tried a lot to get the desired json format but failed.please help me out to solve this problem

Comment: All I see in your desired format is that it has random attributes (like storeId or brandId) removed from `offers` collection items compared to the ones in the actual output.

Comment: @marekful i need filters to be an array that contains filter name and other datails

Comment: @SUJITH, your format looks correct to me.  It just looks like your "desired format" JSON has more attributes & data than your JSON does.